# Can multiple lasers be concentrated in a circular area using some optical arrangements?

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, laser-interaction

Can multiple lasers be concentrated in a circular area using some optical arrangements such as using a paraboloid surface?

If yes, why do in high laser power systems do they use only 2D arrays of diode lasers ? I am sorry for my lack of knowledge in the optics field